# Undefined Variable that has already been printed on console log

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

OnClick I want a dialog button to pop up, the dialog is to have a uniqueId and have an iframe inside it. This is my code:

```
$( ".insertDetailsDiv" ).click(function() {
        var idName = $(this).attr("id");
        var idNameBase = idName.replace('DetailsButton', '');

        var  iframeSRC = idNameBase+".php";
        $("<div class='idNameDialogDivClass'></div>").dialog();
        $(".idNameDialogDivClass").each(function() {
            $(this).uniqueId();
            var  idNameDialogDiv = $(this).attr("id");
            console.log(idNameDialogDiv);
        });

        $("<iframe></iframe>", { 
                id: idNameBase, 
                src: iframeSRC
        }).appendTo('#'+idNameDialogDiv);
});
```

However my console log (chrome) outputs

```
ui-id-6
Uncaught ReferenceError: idNameDialogDiv is not defined
```

I don-t understand, the console log outputs the variable and then javascript doesn-t recognise the variable.

Comment: probably its undefined in this part:: .appendTo('#'+idNameDialogDiv);

Comment: Yes it is, but isn-t that parsed after it has been created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare that variable `idNameDialogDiv` outside of the `.each()` function,

```
$( ".insertDetailsDiv" ).click(function() {
        var idName = $(this).attr("id");
        var idNameBase = idName.replace('DetailsButton', '');
        var idNameDialogDiv = null;  // Declare here.

        var  iframeSRC = idNameBase+".php";
        $("<div class='idNameDialogDivClass'></div>").dialog();
        $(".idNameDialogDivClass").each(function() {
            $(this).uniqueId();
            idNameDialogDiv = $(this).attr("id");
            console.log(idNameDialogDiv);
        });

        $("<iframe></iframe>", { 
                id: idNameBase, 
                src: iframeSRC
        }).appendTo('#'+idNameDialogDiv);  // This was the place where the error was caused
});
```

Comment: Any tips to make my code generally better then? What was the most crappy part?

Comment: @Gamemorize `idNameDialogDiv = $(this).attr("id");` Code inside the .each is irritating my eyes.. Since id is a unique thing, we don't need to write code like that.. :)

Answer (score 0):

idNameDialogDiv is a variable you've defined in the scope of the `$.each` function. It is not available outside of this block

```
$(".idNameDialogDivClass").each(function() {        // <- function declaration
    $(this).uniqueId();
    var  idNameDialogDiv = $(this).attr("id");      // <- variable declaration
    console.log(idNameDialogDiv);
});
```

You'll need to move this variable outside the function in order to access it where you currently are

Comment: @Gamemorize move the `var idNameDialogDiv` out of the `each` function. Check to make sure that there are actually elements with the class `idNameDialogDivClass`

Comment: Thanks again, I accepted the faster/fuller answer though, cheers though!